# get_the_category_list or get_the_tag_list for custom post types and taxonomies?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, theme-twenty-eleven

Basically I've setup a custom post type and taxonomy for a set type of posts and I'm creating a child theme from twentyeleven.

When I use the default WP Posts and then I tag them and categorize them, get_the_category_list and get_the_tag_list do their work and display below the post.

Now I would like to do the same with my custom post type with two taxonomies that behave as tags and categories. Is there a way I can do this without having to redo the work that  get_the_category_list and get_the_tag_list already do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the generic [`get_the_term_list()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list) for all taxonomies.

Comment: I pretty much figured it out a few minutes after posting the question by looking at category-template.php. I'm going to accept this as the answer as it is the simplest method. Thanks.